# Automatic this.props.children in nested components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm going through the [react-router-tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial) and am on [lesson 5](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links) and have a question.

The lesson talks about defining a `NavLink` component that wraps the `Link` component, and gives it an `activeClassName` attribute, which is used as follows:

```
<NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
```

In the lesson, they define the `NavLink` component as follows:

```
// modules/NavLink.js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/>
  }
})
```

What confuses me is the use of the self closing `Link` component. No where in the definition of `NavLink` does it say to put the `this.props.children` inside of the `Link` component. I tried it out explicitly as follows:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active">{this.props.children}</Link>
        )
    }
}
```

and that also works as expected. My question is why? What allows the self closing `Link` component in their definition to automatically take the `this.props.children` of the `NavLink` and put it inside the `Link` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats due to the spread attribute on the Link component `{...this.props}`. This allows all the properties of `this.props` that includes `this.props.children` to be passed into the Link component. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes) is a reference of that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've seen the documentation about using the spread operator for this.props, but thought it only did attributes for a tag, not the content of the tag. Nailed it!